# Powershell get all errors not just first

Tags: powershell

I have a command like so:

```
(($remoteFiles | Where-Object { -not ($_ | Select-String -Quiet -NotMatch -Pattern '^[a-f0-9]{32}(  )') }) -replace '^[a-f0-9]{32}(  )', '$0=  ' -join "`n") | ConvertFrom-StringData
```

sometimes it throws a

```
ConvertFrom-StringData : Data item 'a3512c98c9e159c021ebbb76b238707e' in line 'a3512c98c9e159c021ebbb76b238707e  =  My Pictures/Tony/Automatic Upload/Tony’s iPhone/2022-10-08 21-46-21 (2).mov' 
is already defined.
```

BUT I believe there to be more and the error is only thrown on the FIRST occurrence, is there a way to get all of the errors so I can act upon them?

Answer (score 2):

> is there a way to get all of the errors

I'm afraid there is *not*, because what [`ConvertFrom-StringData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-stringdata) reports on encountering a problem is a *statement-terminating* error, which means that it aborts its execution instantly, without considering further input.

---

You'd have to perform your own analysis of the input in order to detect multiple problems, such as *duplicate keys*; e.g.:

```
@'
a = 1
b = 2
a = 10
c = 3
b = 20
'@ | ForEach-Object {
  $_ -split '\r?\n' |
    Group-Object { ($_ -split '=')[0].Trim() } |
    Where-Object Count -gt 1 |
    ForEach-Object {
      Write-Error "Duplicate key: $($_.Name)"
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Write-Error: Duplicate key: a
Write-Error: Duplicate key: b
```